# Jquery Focus-Out issue in IE on two textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Two text-boxes and both of then have Focus-Out event

```
$('.ClassofTxtbx1').focusout(function(){ });
$('.ClassofTxtbx2').focusout(function(){ });
```

when I enter something in textbox1 and hit tab, focus goes to 2nd textbox and both textbox FOCUSOUT event getting called.This is wht happens in IE-9 but works in CHROME.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `blur()` instead:

```
$('.ClassofTxtbx1').blur(function(){ });
$('.ClassofTxtbx2').blur(function(){ });
```

`focusout` may have issues, if both of your text boxes belong to the same parent.

Comment: Actually i am showing modal popup [message] on both txtbox focus out .So modal pop up will open if focus out triggered.

Comment: So? It does not change anything.

Comment: Blur and focusout are essentially the same thing

Comment: It opens modal pop up twice when i focus out from 1st textbox by hitting TAB it goes to textbox2 focus out event also

Comment: I do not understand. Have you even tried to change it to `blur`? Can you demonstrate what is wrong with a fiddle?